# How to change a unified AzureAD group email without using ExchangeOnline?

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

There is a unified Microsoft 365 group in Azure AD that requires a name change. With this change, I would also like to update its email but it does not seem to work. I have tried changing MailNickname but it does not change the email group property either. This is the way I tried doing it in PowerShell.

```
 Set-AzureADMSGroup -Id $GroupID -DisplayName $NewGroupName -MailNickname $NewGroupName.replace(' ','_')
```

This MailNickname property change does not produce new aliases either.

Searching online for the answer, it seems people try to use the ExchangeOnline command "Set-UnifiedGroup" which I'd like to avoid, and use mostly AzureAD module-related commands.

Do you know whether this would be possible?

Also, why does changing MailNickname not change anything but that exact property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results***

I created one **unified** Microsoft 365 group in Azure AD with below commands:

```
Connect-AzureAD
New-AzureADMSGroup -Description “Unified Group” -DisplayName “Sri Unified Group” -MailEnabled $true -SecurityEnabled $true -MailNickname “SriGroup” -GroupTypes “Unified”
```

**Response:**

[image]

To get full details of this **unified group**, I ran below command:

```
 Get-AzureADMSGroup -SearchString Sri | fl
```

**Response:**

[image]

To change the group name and its email, I ran the **same command** as you like below:

```
$GroupID = (Get-AzureADMSGroup -SearchString Sri).Id
$NewGroupName = "Devi Unified Group"
Set-AzureADMSGroup -Id $GroupID -DisplayName $NewGroupName -MailNickname $NewGroupName.replace(' ','_')
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I fetch the **full details** of this group, only `DisplayName` and `MailNickname` changed but **`Mail`** is **same** as below:

```
 Get-AzureADMSGroup -SearchString Devi | fl
```

**Response:**

[image]

Alternatively, you can change it via **Microsoft 365 Admin Center** portal by signing in with **Admin account** like below:

*Go to Microsoft 365 Admin Center -> Teams & groups -> Active teams & groups -> Your group -> Edit Aliases*

[image]

Click on this option to edit **Primary email address** like below:

[image]

You can change **Primary email address** value and select `Done` like below:

[image]

You can **delete** the existing Alias if you don't need them like below:

[image]

When I fetch the **full details** of that group again from PowerShell, I got the results successfully with new **`Mail`** like below:

[image]

If you want to change group **`email address`** from PowerShell, it is possible only with ***Exchange Online*** commands not from ***Azure AD***.

**Reference:**

[How to update Azure AD MS Group Mail and ProxyAddresses field using PowerShell by **MMNandM**](https://serverfault.com/questions/1088971/how-to-update-azure-ad-ms-group-mail-and-proxyaddresses-field-using-powershell?rq=1)